# Calculating ripple voltage across sense resistor (SEPIC DC-DC Converter)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, sepic

I am designing a SEPIC DC-DC converter based on the LT3758 (Analog Devices). In the data sheet the maximum switch ripple current percentage is calculated using the ripple voltage across the sense resistor using the following equation

[image: (p15 of the data sheet)]

My understanding is that since the typical SENSE current limit threshold is 100mV, the ripple voltage across the sense resistor is 110-80=30mV, but I am no where near convinced of this.

[This](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT3758-3758A.pdf) is the datasheet for the part. The equation is on page 15, Sense current limit threshold is on page 3 and a block diagram is on page 9.

Any help would be appreciated

Here's the block diagram:
[image]

Comment: If DC from load regulation is the signal and ripple is the noise you certainly do not want a sense signal with 0dB SNR. Poor assumption.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm sure it is a bad assumption (in fact I was pretty sure that I was wrong), but I'm not sure what a good assumption would be. Baring iterative testing I'm not sure how one would find the ripple

Comment: p17 starts the calculations to achieve 1% ripple

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the ripple on p17 the total output ripple which would be different from the ripple across the sense resistor? There is a diagram on p14 that shows the the voltage across Rsense and includes the $\delta$ Vsense. Or is it just a matter of choosing what ripple I want

Comment: Your goal is 1% ripple. If you suppress all of it your phase margin reduces, if more , some cct may degrade

Comment: So if the goal is 1% does that mean I should assume 1% across the sense resistor? Since Vsense(peak) is 80mV that would make \$\Delta\$ Vsense=800uV. To add to my confusion, Vsense(max)=Vsense(peak)-0.5*\$\Delta\$Vsense, but earlier in the data sheet is says that Vsense(max) is nominally 110mV which would make \$\Delta\$Vsense negative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that \$\chi\$ is simply a design parameter that is related to the voltage ripple (or current ripple) across the sense resistor. As per page 22 of the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3757-3757a.pdf), 'A good starting point for \$\chi\$ is 0.2 and careful evaluation of system stability should be made to ensure adequate design margin'. So, the only way to know if the value chosen for \$\chi\$ is acceptable is by designing and analyzing the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

if \$\chi=\dfrac{ΔV_{SENSE}}{80mV −0.5 • ΔV_{SENSE}} = 0.01\$  (1%)

then \${ΔV_{SENSE}} = \dfrac{80mV −0.5 • ΔV_{SENSE}}{100}\$

then \$ΔV_{SENSE}+ \dfrac{ΔV_{SENSE}}{200} = \dfrac{80mV }{100}\$

or \$ΔV_{SENSE} ≈800 \mu V \$